# webserver serve file request with delay (htaccess)

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, htaccess, delay

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to configure a webserver so that requests for files will be served with a delay. So for example if i were to serve this file http://www.example.url/picture.jpg, i want the data transfer to start only 2 seconds after the request has been made... or any other arbitrary number. Now i'm a complete noob to this kind of stuff, all i know is that the htaccess file is what i'm expected to use to do any configuration type like things. Is there a way to make this happen somehow?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this can be done directly in htaccess, but how about doing it on the webpage itself, via a meta?

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL='http://www.example.com/mypicture.jpg'" />
```

if you need to use htaccess, you could add this image page to page2.html, then in htaccess redirect to it like this

```
Redirect 302 mypicture.jpg http://page2.html
```

I have not tested this, but I think it might work

Comment: I forgot to mention, but its not for use with a website. I need to specifically configure it on the server side, if possible at all of course...

Comment: could you maybe make a little perl script, that you run, and add the delay there, before it start the download?

Comment: I don't know, would this be independent from how the file is accessed? I have no experience with perl but i'm willing to figure it out if that would offer a solution.

Comment: This solution would be independent from access method. The same effect can be achieved with PHP or any other language used on a server.

Comment: Ok thats good to know, how do i get started? I figure it wouldn't be too much of an effort to put something like this together i think?

Comment: maybe that should be another question maybe even on another forum.

Comment: I will ask on stackoverflow and look for someone who is willing to help me out there.. There's one thing i don't really get though... If someone browses to an image file how does a perl or php script influence that directly?

Comment: you basically ask the user to get the image trough the perl script. I am not a developer, so I am sure the guys at stackoverflow will help you better, but basically you ask perl, and perl fetches for you. (or any other script language).